# Serverside Datatables finds entries marked as deleted

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, activerecord, datatables

I am using Server-side Datatables (and CodeIgniter) to show data.

I can't directly delete entries from the Database (guideline of the project, unfortunately), so I am working with deleted-Flags, a column in the DB table called 'deleted' (tinyint(1) since MySQL automatically changed it from BOOLEAN to that).

For the server side processing I'm using the script provided at https://github.com/blake-nouribekian/codeigniter-datatables/blob/master/data.php, with some small changes

```
// Columns use for SELECT part of the query. These names are not being escaped, so subqueries etc are possible.
$aColumns = array('events.id AS id', 'title', "FROM_UNIXTIME(start, '%d.%m.%Y') AS start", "FROM_UNIXTIME(start, '%H:%i') AS start_time", '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_bookings WHERE id_event = events.id AND confirmed IS NOT NULL) AS participants', 'max_participants');
// Column names for WHERE clause (important for stuff like subqueries).
$aColumnNames = array('id', 'title', "start", "start", '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_bookings WHERE id_event = events.id AND confirmed IS NOT NULL)', 'max_participants');
// Column for deleted flag in the DB.
$deleted_column = 'deleted';
// DB table to use
$sTable = 'events';
// no deleted entries
$this->db->where(Event_Model::$dbDeletedFlag, 0);
```

Initially, the data is shown correct, no entries marked as deleted show up. As soon as I type something into the search field, however, it finds ALL entries that match '... LIKE %input%'. I've gone wild with the $this->db->where(Event_Model::$dbDeletedFlag, 0); command, placing it at every possible line, still no improvement. It shows the entries marked as deleted. The where commands somehow don't work, when the search field is used.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers so far. I'm posting the whole function right here:

```
public function server_processing() {
    // EDIT THIS
    // -----
    // Columns use for SELECT part of the query. These names are not being escaped, so subqueries etc are possible.
    $aColumns = array('events.id AS id', 'title', "FROM_UNIXTIME(start, '%d.%m.%Y') AS start", "FROM_UNIXTIME(start, '%H:%i') AS start_time", '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_bookings WHERE id_event = events.id AND confirmed IS NOT NULL) AS participants', 'max_participants');
    // Column names for WHERE clause (important for stuff like subqueries).
    $aColumnNames = array('id', 'title', "start", "start", '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_bookings WHERE id_event = events.id AND confirmed IS NOT NULL)', 'max_participants');
    // Column for deleted flag in the DB.
    $deleted_column = 'deleted';
    // DB table to use
    $sTable = 'events';
    // no deleted entries
    $this->db->where(Event_Model::$dbDeletedFlag, 0);
    // -------

    $iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
    $iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
    $iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
    $iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
    $sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
    $sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);

    // Paging
    if (isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1') {
      $this->db->limit($this->db->escape_str($iDisplayLength), $this->db->escape_str($iDisplayStart));
    }

    // Ordering
    if (isset($iSortCol_0)) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < intval($iSortingCols); $i++) {
        $iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_' . $i, true);
        $bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_' . intval($iSortCol), true);
        $sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_' . $i, true);

        if ($bSortable == 'true') {
          $this->db->order_by($aColumnNames[intval($this->db->escape_str($iSortCol))], $this->db->escape_str($sSortDir));
        }
      }
    }

    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    if (isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch)) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_' . $i, true);

        // Individual column filtering
        if (isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true') {
          $this->db->or_like($aColumnNames[$i], $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
        }
      }
    }

    // Select Data
    $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ' . str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false);
    $rResult = $this->db->get($sTable);


    // Data set length after filtering
    $this->db->select('FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');
    $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->get()->row()->found_rows;

    // Total data set length
    $iTotal = $this->db->count_all($sTable);

    // Output
    $output = array(
        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
        'aaData' => array()
    );

    $output['aaData'] = array();
    foreach ($rResult->result_array() as $aRow) {
      // EDIT THIS
      // --------
      $row = array(
          '<a class="detail_link link" href="javascript:void(0);" data-event-id="' . $aRow['id'] . '">' . $aRow['title'] . '</a>',
          $aRow['start'],
          $aRow['start_time'],
          $aRow['participants'] . ' / ' . $aRow['max_participants']
      );
      if ($this->auth->access(Auth::Admin, true, false)) {
        $row[] = '<img class="edit_link" data-event-id="' . $aRow['id'] . '" src="' . base_url() . 'img/icons/glyphicons_150_edit.png"> <img class="delete_link" data-event-id="' . $aRow['id'] . '" src="' . base_url() . 'img/icons/glyphicons_192_circle_remove.png">';
      }
      // --------
      $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
  }
```

Thank you for your efforts!

**EDIT 2**

I think, the problem is, that the generated SQL-Statement looks like this, when the Search field is used:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE deleted = 0 OR field LIKE %input%
```

Whereas it rather should be:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE field LIKE %input% AND deleted = 0
```

I just don't know really, how the Active records build the SQL statements, in order to solve this problem

Comment: You're using the same query to retrieve the original records and filter the data? I'm not even seeing the code LIKE %input% in the above. For the record there is no unfortunately about it, deleting records from your tables screw up the indexes requiring them to be rebuilt and taking away their effectiveness. You're doing it right by just flagging records as deleted.

Comment: Can you display more of the controller (or model) code? I would like to see how `$aColumns`, `$aColumnNames` and so on are used, and I want to see all the active record statements in effect. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, okay, so no more deleting from Databases then :) I edited the post and provided the whole function.

Comment: @PatrickManser I reformulated my post taking into account your updated information.  Please review when ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, the problem seems to be in how Active Record builds up the `LIKE` fragments of the `WHERE` clause.

```
if (isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch)) {
    // Build up the SQL manually. First, initialize SQL string.  
    // This clause will be ANDed to the other WHERE clauses; 
    // Use parentheses to isolate the OR in the inner clauses
    $sql = "("; // 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
      $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_' . $i, true);

      // Individual column filtering
      if (isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true') {
        //$this->db->or_like($aColumnNames[$i], $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
        $sql_tag = ($i==0) ? "" : " OR "; // don't need OR before the first field
        $sql .= $sql_tag . $aColumnNames[$i] . " LIKE " . $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch);
      }
    }
    $sql .= ")"; // close parentheses
    $this->db->where($sql);  // this will add to the WHERE clause using AND
}
```

What I would do is build up the the `LIKE` clause manually.  You need to allow for multiple fields to be searchable.  If I got the details right, your final query should resemble:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE deleted = 0 
  AND (field1 LIKE '%input%' OR field2 LIKE '%input%' OR field3 LIKE '%input%')
```

assuming you have three fields to search.

Comment: Yeah, initially it was $this->db->where($deleted_column, 0); with the same results, so I tried Event_Model::$dbDeletedFlag instead. There's no difference between those actually, though, they both just hold the value 'deleted'. Sorry, forgot to mention that. And 0 in the Database means, it's not deleted

Comment: Great! When you posted the query string, I saw what the problem was, so well done to you for making the effort to clarify things.  All the best!